# stack declaration segmentation fault

Tags: c++

just my practice. 
//read a sentence with "()" in it and replace everything in () with "(deleted)".

1)read the sentence to a vector.

2) stack the vector into a stack >.
3) find the positions of both "("
   and ")"
4) remove the elements and replace with "(deleted)" in
   vector
5) output the vector.

ie. input "this is (a) duck", output should be "this is (deleted) duck". thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    cout<<"please enter a series of words with parenthes"<<endl;
    vector<string> svec;
    string word;
    while (cin>>word)
        svec.push_back(word);
    stack<string, vector<string> > strStack(svec);
    vector<string>::iterator pos1 ,pos2;
    for (vector<string>::iterator counter=svec.end(); strStack.empty()==false; --counter)
    {
        if(strStack.top()==")") pos1=counter-1;
        if(strStack.top()=="(") { pos2=counter-1; break; }
        strStack.pop();     
    }
    svec.insert(svec.erase(pos2,pos1),"(deleted)");
    for(vector<string>::iterator iter=svec.begin(); iter!=svec.end(); )
        cout<<*iter++<<" "<<flush;
return 0;
}
```

sorry. output is: I think the problem is  stack > strStack(svec);
cause I couldn't cout stack; the codes above this should be fine (i cout'ed them);

```
please enter a series of words with parenthes
this is (a) duck
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You're using `counter` to move from `svec.end()` to...well, beyond the beginning of `svec`. Use `rbegin()` and stop iterating when you hit `rend()`.

Comment: @w00te: he said something about seg fault

Comment: I just updated the output @w00te

Comment: My bad, I didn't read thoroughly enough - appologies and +1 :)

Comment: What do you discover when you run the program inside a debugger? What line raises the segmentation fault?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is simply broken: It only handles some *very specific* cases, namely when there are single words consisting of only a parentheses. Failing that, you never assign `pos1` and `pos2`, leading to our beloved "undefined behaviour".

At the very least, *make sure you never use uninitialized variables* (#1). As a bonus, we check if there was a match (#2):

```
vector<string>::iterator pos1 = svec.end(), pos2 = pos1; // #1: never uninitialized

// ...

if (pos1 != pos2)   // #2: only if we found something
    svec.insert(svec.erase(pos2,pos1),"(deleted)");
```

Comment: I just realized that I need to use stack<char> instead of <string>. thanks. I am waiting for #2. Even an advice on code format would help.

Comment: @ihm: Perhaps, though you'll have to modify the `insert` statement accordingly.

Comment: I think I need  to modify every statement that has pos1 and pos2 in it. since they are most likely uninitialized.